# Parse log file for lines containing 2 strings and the lines inbetween

Tags: regex, string, powershell, parsing

I am trying to parse some large log files to detect occurrences of a coding bug.  Identifying the defect is finding a sequence of strings on different lines with a date in between.  I am terrible at describing things so posting an example:

```
    <Result xmlns="">
    <Failure exceptionClass="processing" exceptionDetail="State_Open::Buffer Failed - none">
      <SystemID>ffds[sid=EPS_FFDS, 50] Version:01.00.00</SystemID>
      <Description>Lo
ck Server failed </Description>
    </Failure>
  </Result>
</BufferReply>
7/22/2017 8:41:15 AM | SomeServer | Information | ResponseProcessing.TreatEPSResponse() is going to process a response or event. Response.ServiceID [Server_06] Response.Response [com.schema.fcc.ffds.BufferReply]
```

I will be searching for multiple instances of this sequence through multiple logs: `Buffer Failed` on followed by `Server_#`.
The `Server_#` can be any 2-digit number and will never be on the same line.
`Buffer failed` will never repeat prior to `Server_#` being found.
The date and time that is in between but guessing that if this is possible it would be captured also.

Ideally, I would pipe something like  this to another file

```
Buffer Failed - none"   7/22/2017 8:41:15 AM [Server_06]
```

I have attempted a few things like

```
Select-String 'Failed - none(.*?)Response.Response' -AllMatches
```

but it doesn't seem to work across lines.

Comment: Is your log file in XML?  I'd recommend `Import-CliXml`

Comment: If your file is a XML, use XML commands and not string commands.
http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-read-xml-files,2-895.html

Comment: It is not an XML file, but even if it was I would not be able to use any 3rd party utilities as servers that files are located on have PCI compliance for credit card transactions.  The errors I am searching for are reported into logging in an XML format, but the logging is not XML I guess it would be possible to filter XML data only into another file and then attempt to go through it there if that is the only solution I can come up with

Answer (score 1):

`Select-String` can only match text spanning multiple lines if it receives the input as a single string. Plus, `.` normally matches any character *except* line feeds (`\n`). If you want it to match line feeds as well you must prefix your regular expression with the modifier `(?s)`. Otherwise you need an expression that does include line feeds, e.g. `[\s\S]` or `(.|\n)`.

It might also be advisable to anchor the match at `expressionDetail` rather than the actual detail, because that makes the match more flexible.

Something like this should give you the result you're looking for:

```
$re = '(?s)exceptionDetail="(.*?)".*?(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [AP]M).*?\[(.*?)\] Response\.Response'

... | Out-String |
    Select-String -Pattern $re -AllMatches |
    Select -Expand Matches |
    ForEach-Object { '{0} {1} [{2}]' -f $_.Groups[1..3] }
```

The expression uses non-greedy matches and 3 capturing groups for extracting exception detail, timestamp and servername.

Comment: Getting "An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)"  in here and not sure why (\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [AP]M)

Comment: @NoodlesPokerandSportsMedia regex101.com doesn't like unescaped forward slashes. Please do your tests in an actual PowerShell console.