# With PowerShell, search a text file for multiple matches and grouping results

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell-4.0

I wasn't sure how to word that.  Anyway, I have a file of "orders" like this:

```
Packslip 123000-01    07/16/18
ship to
add1
add2
add3
city, state
country zip
[1. item part number] [item description] [item qty]
[2. item part number] [item description] [item qty]
[3. item part number] [item description] [item qty]
Packslip 321001-01    07/16/18
ship to
add1
add2
add3
city, state
country zip
[1. item part number] [item description] [item qty]
```

Each order begins at the line starting with "Packslip".
Each order could have any number of items.

What I would like to get out of this text file is something like this:

```
[123000-01] [item1 part number] [item qty]
[123000-01] [item2 part number] [item qty]
[123000-01] [item3 part number] [item qty]
[321001-01] [item1 part number] [item qty]
...and so on...
```

the brackets can be ignored, they are only there for this example to help separate data elements.

Using `Get-Content`, I am able to get the packing slip/order numbers (i.e., "123001-01") just fine, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the [item part numbers] and [quantities] in such a way that they are tied to the correct order number.

My question is this:  How can I go about searching this text file and grouping results based on variable patterns and variable results?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47997088/1630171) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45596637/1630171) have been asked before. Please do your own research first, try to come up with a solution, *then* ask for help on SO when there's something specific in your code that you can't get to work the way you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to write something, if you don't have the real data, but the abstraction you provided. I made the following assumptions about your data:

1. The item id does not contain white-spaces and is followed by a white-space
2. The quantity does not contain white-spaces and follows a white-space
3. The number of rows between the packslip number and the first item is fixed

If those assumption are true, this should work:

```
param (
    [string]$in = "example.txt",
    [string]$out = "out.txt"
)
if(Test-Path $out -PathType Leaf){
    Clear-Content $out
}

$packslip_regex = "Packslip.*"
$line_number = 0 

foreach($line in Get-Content $in) {
    if($line -match $packslip_regex){
        $packslip_number = $line.Split(" ")[1]
        $line_number = 0
    }

    if($line_number -gt 6){
        $item = $line.Split(" ")
        $item_id = $item[0]
        $item_number = $item[$item.Count - 1]
        $out_string = "$packslip_number $item_id $item_number"
        $out_string | Out-File $out -Append
    }

    $line_number = $line_number + 1
}
```

I read in the packslip number, then I skip a fixed amount of rows, then I read in all rows that follow till I hit another packslip number.

You call the script like this:

```
.\script.ps1 -in example.txt -out output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next snippet.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\packslips.dat){
  if ($line -match '^Packslip\s+(?<packslip>\S+).*$') {
    $packslip = $matches.packslip
  } elseif ($line -match '^\d+.\s+(?<partnumber>\S+).*\b(?<itemqty>\d+)\s*$') {
    "[${packslip}] [$($matches.partnumber)] [$($matches.itemqty)]"
  }
}
```